# How to strike out the text of the corresponding checkbox in my to-do app when I check the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>To-do App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
            <h1>Tasks</h1><br>

            <ul id="myList">

            </ul>

            <input type="text" id="myText"><br><br>
            <button onclick="addTask()">Add task</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
var x=1;
function addTask() {
    var liNode = document.createElement("LI");    // create a <li> node
    var myTask=document.getElementById("myText").value;    //store the value of input string
    if (myTask!="")
        {

        var cb = document.createElement("INPUT");    //create an input element
        cb.type="checkbox";
        cb.id=x;

        liNode.appendChild(cb);    //append the checkbox to <li>

        var text = document.createTextNode(" "+myTask);    //create the text node after the checkbox
        liNode.appendChild(text);    //append the text node to the <li>

        document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(liNode);    //append the <li> to the <ul> with id="myList"

        document.getElementById("myText").value=null;
        x++;
        }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the text, corresponding to the check boxes to get modified in someway (like strike-through to show the task has been done) when I check them. Please provide the solution in pure JavaScript only.

Comment: this is what I just came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/wfm7fmxy/1/ (no styling, just functionality)... if you think it's good, I can make it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets get through this now, First of all we have this piece of code:

```
 document.getElementById(YourCheckBoxIDHere).innerHTML = "<s>"+ document.getElementById(YourCheckBoxIDHere).innerHTML +"</s>"
```

Above code adds the strike through, But how do we let it work on check?

Simply we put the code here after creating your checkbox:

```
document.getElementById(x).addEventListener("change", CrossMeOut);
```

And declare your function:

```
function myFunction(x) {
    x.innerHTML = "<s>"+ x.innerHTML +"</s>
}
```

Of course you might have to deal with a few minor things probably when applying it specially to your code. But I hope this post has put you at the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wfm7fmxy/1/

What it basically does is create a `li` element that contains a checkbox and the task text like you did (only noteable difference: `id` is set on task `li` instead of checkbox), and then adds a `onchange` function to the checkbox that calls another function `toggleTask()`:

```
function toggleTask()
{
    var task = document.getElementById(this.parentNode.id);
    if (this.checked)
    {
        task.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    }
    else
    {
        task.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    }
}
```

This either strikes through the task if the checkbox gets checked or reverts it otherwise.